# Development paradigms of ML libraries

Tags: libraries, machine-learning

I know that Tensorflow use symbolic model-building APIs where the developers can use them to build static computational graphs. 
Whereas Pytorch offer imperative programming paradigm where it performs computations as it goes.

Could anyone help me understand the development paradigms of Scikit-Learn, Keras, Caffe and Theano? Do they use imperative development paradigm or symbolic APIs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the full picture of your question so I'll try my best.

First of all, I'll make some assumptions:

1. You actually meant Neural Networks instead of Machine Learning
2. You meant paradigm by the system design and flexibility
3. You want a chronological view of the design evolution

**Discamer**: I'm a ML framework(based on applied neural science) author. And I adore PyTorch's design. My view may be biased and limited to my field. Also the development of NN frameworks are intertwined, it is possible the major frameworks didn't invent the solution themselves but have a better implementation. I'm only capable of telling a brief timeline.

---

### 2003 - libfann

Let's examine an very early neural network library - [libfann](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/)

`libfann`'s design is very simple. `fann_create_standard(num_layers, ...)` creates a neural network and `fann_train_on_data` trains the neural network. And that's it. There's no way to add a convolution layer, [limited activation functions](https://libfann.github.io/fann/docs/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_activationfunc_enum), no optimizer variants (it does support algorithm we consider inferior today, like quick backprop and simulated annealing).

The code (for MNIST) generally looks like this:

```
FANN* ann = fann_create_standard(4, 784, 128, 128, 10);
// Now somehow read your traning data and put it in fann_train_data
// Or alternatively use fann_read_train_from_file, but it reads text files
fann_train_data * data = somehow_read_data();
// Then we train the network with at most 100 epochs and early terminate
// if loss < 0.001
fann_train_on_data(ann, data, 100, 10, 0.001f);
```

As you see. There's not much space for fancy networks like a GAN or a RNN. (To be accurate, it is possible by messing with the internal pointers. But that's not a good idea.) You define a network with a small set parameters, train it, done. This is the exact same way `sklearn` works.

### 2007 - Theano

[Theano](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/) is more like [Mathemetica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) rather than a neural network library. It is not designed for Neural Netowrk but happens that Theano can be (ab)used to build neural networks and calculate gradients. Theano performs symbolic math. Given the equation `y = 9*sin(3*x) + a`. It applies the steps you learned in collage calculus class to derive `y' = 27*cos(3*x)`. Chain rule, and all the jazz.

This functionality can be abused for neural networks - not that it is efficient or what, but it works. The down side of doing calculus this way is solving the derivative may take a while. Up to minutes for a long and wide recurrent neural network (comparing to milliseconds using autograd). Solving the derivative of GPT-2 this way will likely take months if not years or just run out of memory.

### 2014 - Caffe

Fast forward to the Deep Learning boom in 2014. [Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) made a huge (and in my option, logical) step forward in the design by utilizing [prototxt](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html) to define layers and allow layers to reference each other using their names. Now the network architecture is liberated from the fix form of API definition. This freed the network from simple network definitions used by `sklearn` and `libfann` without the need to do all the calculus using `Theano`.

### 2015 - TensorFlow 1.x

[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) is a very large leap in the system design. The problem with Caffe is that prototxt is very verbose and slow to code. TensorFlow solves both Caffe and Theano's problem by a. express operations in code and b. apply [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) instead of symbolic differentiation. In essences, automatic differentiation is a way of calculating the derivative at a certain point of a function without actually doing calculus if we know the derivative of all of it's components. Which then enables TensorFlow to express all possible neural networks as tensor operations.

**I believe** the static nature of TensorFlow comes from the fact that automatic differentiation can only be done after the network is fully defined and optimization reasons (GPU isn't as well developed at 2011 when TensorFlow first developed (or called DistBelief at the time)).

### 2016 - PyTorch

[PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) is a joined project among [Torch](http://torch.ch/), [Caffe2](https://caffe2.ai/) and other projects. In fact Torch have been using automatic differentiation and dynamic graph way before TensorFlow. But it didn't get as much flare because Torch runs on [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) instead of Python. PyTorch is just that. A Python and better version of Torch. Instead of requiring a fully formed compute graph, Torch/PyTorch evaluates expressions eagerly while retain the ability to go backwards.

### Keras

Keras originally is just a wrapper to make TensorFlow easier to use. There's nothing to it.

---

To be honest, everything after TensorFlow are based on automatic differentiation. The only differences are how they are implemented and the limitations of their implementation. In fact, most frameworks (TensorFlow, PyTorch, Chainer, MXNet, NLTK, tiny-dnn, you name it) and some frameworks before TensorFlow (Torch, aurograd) uses automatic differentiation. The only difference is if they support dynamic graph. And all of them support dynamic graphs now (TF supports it since TF 2.0).